# Method of premature change of president and vice president in alternate version of the USA

Tags: alternate-history, politics, law, alternate-reality, united-states

I'm working on a world (for a series of stories) not much different from our reality.

The laws are almost same to the letter - the timeline diverged ~2013 but with no important changes in the law.

What would, in such world, cause a change of both president and VP at once (or in very short time one from another)? 
Take into consideration that only non-violent measures allowed.

Research: Yes, [impeachement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Impeachment) is an option. But then can it happen to both officials (legally)? Are there maybe another options?

*DISCLAIMER: This is not, in any way, about current USA administration nor about my likes or dislikes of one party or the other. It is an alternate reality story.*

Comment: The simple solution would be for both of them to have committed impeachable offenses (the same offense, or different ones) and to bail before the investigation can really sink its teeth into them. Pretty much the Watergate scenario if Ford had also been part of it.

Comment: Hmm, I guess that is also some way to do that, and if the offence was serious enough they might want to run away - thank you @Cadence! :)

Comment: Now that I think about it, I suspect the old President and VP could still appoint someone to be the replacement VP on their way out, who would become President, but they'd have a pretty big cloud over their whole administration... that's part of why this isn't really properly answerable - what the law says isn't as important as the political and social ramifications.

Comment: Widespread organized election fraud invalidates the election *before* the swearing in after the election ?  I'm afraid I'm not familiar enough with US law to do more that suggest the idea.

Comment: @Cadence - it seems that it's not a big problem. VP can be appointed only if the previous one vacated (which takes a while) - that means that in the "running away" scenario there is no time to waste on waiting for formalties to take place.

Comment: @StephenG If I recall correctly there is currently no means to declare election "null and void" in the US. Adding such a measure would require an amendment to the constitution, which is extremely lengthy - as such I think that this scenario would be unlikely.

Comment: @JBH Thank you for your answer. I have updated the question to match the on-topic standards as described [on the meta](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3300/why-is-my-question-too-story-based-and-how-do-i-get-it-opened/3301#3301)

Comment: Much better and well done. I've voted to reopen and I've deleted my other comments to clean up the comment chain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Redo election mandated by the Supreme Court.**

In your future world, evidence of massive voter fraud is uncovered by an outside entity shortly before the new administration takes office.  The Supreme Court rapidly gets involved.  Even for the partisans on the Court it is too much to just declare the loser the winner.  They mandate that a redo election take place.

Exactly this is going on right now in the United States: there is a redo election in North Carolina which was triggered by discovery of voter fraud.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2019_North_Carolina%27s_9th_congressional_district_special_election

In your timeline, the previous loser wins the redo of the Presidential election.  The previous winners had taken office before, but are vacated within a few weeks of starting and the new winners take their place.

Partisans on the Supreme Court has shown themselves willing to alter the result of a presidential election. (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bush_v._Gore) blocked a recount of confused votes in Florida, which would have changed the outcome of the election if they had happened.  The vote went down on a partisan basis, with the Republican majority blocking the recount and producing an outcome that seated a Republican president.

Comment: Very informative answer - thank you! I didn't know the whole Bush v. Gore situation was so close.